# Comparing percent changed to previous row in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am working with a particularly big dataframe which contains a lot of raw data. I think I have managed to convert the row I am interested in into percent changed with the pct_changed() and inserted it into a new column in the dataframe.

From there I want to compare each row, and get out a result only if the percent exceeds 2%. I tried with conditionals but it printed out a line for each row I had. Here is the code I am working with:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv("tempcsv.csv")
percentile = df['Pressure'].pct_change().fillna(0)

for row in percentile:
    if row > 2:
        print("Above")
```

What I am trying to do is to store the amount of returned "aboves", into a variable which I can use later on. I am pretty new to python so I am learning as I go.

I hope this is explained well enough!

PS: Would it also be possible to take out the median of each 10 rows?

Comment: For median is possible use `df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.index))//10).median()`

Comment: And this returns the iterated median of 10 rows, and if i then apply the pct_change() i get the percentage on the median 10 rows?

Comment: Hmmm, hard to know what you need. Can you add some data sample (10 rows) and desired output? Maybe for smaller saple is possible use median for each 3 rows instead real data 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create condition and sum `True`s values, which are processing like `1`s:

```
percentile = df['Pressure'].pct_change().fillna(0)

a = (percentile > 2).sum()
```